# Parsing Datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

trying to parse this as datetime :

```
2011.03.13-21:15:04+511.0597
```

using

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("2011.03.13-21:15:04+511.0597", 
                                      "yyyy.MM.dd-hh:mm:ss+ttt.tttt",
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")).ToString());
```

but it says unrecognized string.

any idea what im doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried the less formal DateTime.Parse?

Comment: Dates in US are written in mm/dd/yyyy format, which is not the case in your date example.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: It doesn't matter, because he defines his own format anyway.

Comment: Have you tried not passing the culture information.  I can tell you the string your reading does not appear to have a en-us culture ( 03-12-3011 21:15:04+511.0597 ) is more of the en-us format.  I suggest you print a DateTime in the same format and compare the results.  I am going to guess the 24 hour format might also be another source of confusion to the Parse command.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - If that is the should he even be declaring the culture?

Comment: @Ramhound: I thought about that too and wasn't sure, so I didn't say anything about it :)

Comment: @Ramhound: I agree, I think `null` would be more appropriate for this usage.

Comment: Doesn't "t" indicate AM/PM, did you mean to use "f" instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly, but if I trim off everything after the seconds it parses fine.  The `"tt"` part of a custom format is for AM/PM marker, which is one likely target...  I guess you mean `fff` which is the fractional part of the seconds...

Another one is that you have lower-case `"hh"` which is for 12-hour clock only - your string has `21` as the hour portion, which would require upper-case `HH` in your format...

You also can't split two groups of digits with any character, as you have with `ttt.tttt`.  The closest working code I can get to your sample is this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2011.03.13-21:15:04+511", "yyyy.MM.dd-HH:mm:ss+fff", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
```

Comment: problem is im getting this string from a log file which i dont have any control over , so im stuck with that sample ..

Comment: Can you just trim after the period?  Or strip the period before parsing?

Comment: unfortunately i cant, as its kinda important cause it matters , sometimes i have to evaluate the order of the logs and it makes a difference.

Comment: If you strip the period out and then use `ffffff` at the end of the format string, it should work.

Comment: but that would give a different value to the datetime , its like exchanging 100.222$ with 100222$ isnt it ? i could be wrong

Comment: No: I suspect that last portion of your time is milliseconds (511.0597ms); in .NET the `ffff` portion is the fraction of a second.  So, if you strip the decimal point and parse `5110597` using `fffffff` you'll get the right value (0.5110597 of a second).  **HOWEVER**: if your log format doesn't consistently use three digits for the millisecond number (that is, `020` as opposed to `20`) you'll find this gives the wrong answer (as `20` will parse as `0.2 seconds instead of 0.02).  Be very careful!